# Height and Distance problem from Intermediate trigonometry page 58 Q.no 16 by B.C Das

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I solve the all the height and distance problem form Book of intermediate trigonometry by B.C Das except one I am stuck with. I couldn't make a figure of it as I didn't quite understand it. Here is the question

**From station, two light-houses A and B are seen in directions North and $30^\circ$ East of North respectively , if A were one-third as far off as it really is, it would appear due West of B. If the distance of B from the station be 10 miles, find the distance of B from A.**

The first part where A light house is seen at north and B is at $30^{\circ}$ form north towards east, I understood but second part is I am having trouble with. The answer is given as $5\sqrt{13}$ miles.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

In the diagram below, the point $\ A'\ $ is where $\ A\ $ would be if it were only a third the distance $\big($i.e $\ \frac{d}{3}\ $miles$\big)$ from the station $\ S\ $ that it actually is—namely $\ d\ $miles. You're required to find the length of $\ AB\ $.  To do this you'll need to find the value of $\ d\ $ and the lengths of $\ A'A\ $ and $\ A'B\ $.

[image]